Azure DevOps Server with YAML - build directory changes with every job?
Since moving everything YAML to a separate Git repo, I have an odd problem: Now, with every job in the pipeline, the directories on the agents change. The first job uses _work\1, the second _work\2, etc., meaning every job except the first fails, as the directories are empty.
I'm using a product-specific pipeline that extends a base-pipeline (thanks to @rui-jarimba for the excellent suggestion!).
Slightly shortened code:
# FOO-pipeline.yml

name: QEC-${{ parameters.productVersion }}-$(Date:yyMMdd)$(Rev:rr)

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: FOO
      type: git
      name: FOO
      ref: main
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
          - main
    - repository: YAML
      type: git
      name: YAML-Automation
      ref: main
      trigger:
        - none

extends:
  template: /Base-pipeline.yml
  parameters:
    productName: FOO

Stages Build_with_analysis / Build_without_analysis use _work\1 on both agents, everything is working perfectly well (after I combined differnt build jobs into a single one).
Stage Test_All then uses _work\2, the next stage uses _work\3, etc.
# Base-pipleine.yml

parameters:
  - name: productName
    displayName: Name of the product to build
    type: string

stages:
  - stage: Build_without_analysis
    #      ======================
    displayName: 'Build ${{ parameters.productName }}, no analysis'
    pool:
      demands: BuildServer
    jobs:
    - template: /Jobs/jobBuild-All.yml
      parameters:
        productName: ${{ parameters.productName }}
        configuration: Debug
        staticAnalysis: false


  - stage: Build_with_analysis
    #      ===================
    displayName: 'Build ${{ parameters.productName }}, with analysis'
    dependsOn: []
    pool:
      demands: AnalysisServer
    jobs:
    - template: /Jobs/jobBuild-All.yml
      parameters:
        productName: ${{ parameters.productName }}
        configuration: Release
        staticAnalysis: true


  - stage: Test_All
    #      ========
    displayName: 'All tests ${{ parameters.productName }}'
    dependsOn: Build_without_analysis    
    pool:
      demands: BuildServer    
    jobs:
    - template: /Jobs/jobTests-All.yml
      parameters:
        productName: ${{ parameters.productName }}

# jobTests-All.yml

parameters:
- name: productName
  type: string
  default: FOO

jobs:

- job: Run_all_unit_tests
  #    ==================
  displayName: 'All Unit Tests'
  steps:
    - checkout: none  
    - template: /Jobs/${{ parameters.productName }}/jobTests-${{ parameters.productName }}-UnitTests.yml
      parameters:    
        configuration: Debug

What might be the reason?
Haven't been able to find anything related in the Microsoft documentation, or anywhere else online.

Each job (not stage) might be executed by different build agents which might use different working folders and might run in different servers, or even as Docker containers. But I think your problem is not related to that. You're probably not referencing properly the templates that are stored in a different repository. See my answer and read carefully Template usage reference.

I don't see the details of your jobs, i.e. how are you setting paths to your files or folders. For obvious reasons (see my previous comment) you should always use paths combined with predefined variables, such as $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/path/to/my/folder instead of hard-coding paths, as these might change from agent to agent. Never, ever use hard-coded paths such as \\\server1\DevOpsAgent\_work\1\b\ .

You are running multiple stages&jobs, each job is a new session to the agent. The agent will automatically assign folder like _work\1, _work\2 as the workspace for your different jobs, you cannot control the folder assigned. If you would like to make sure the jobs use same workspace, you should put the tasks in one job. Or checkout again/use artifact in new job to have the code.  Please check @jessehouwing's reply below.

As mentioned by @jessehouwing, Jobs are assigned to agents without any assumptions.
Since you are using On-Prem DevOps server, and have different repository resources(FOO, YAML).Checked on my side, if you have different repositories checkout in different jobs in same agent, it could use different folder (_work\1, _work\2) as workspace.
If you would like to get the workingdirectory from previous jobs, one possible workaround is to set variable on previous stage and transfer to next stage. Please note it doesn't change the default working directory on new stage, but jump into the directory in previous stage for tasks like powershell, bash tasks..
For example, on jobs in stage Build_without_analysis, set variable:
    - powershell: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=directory;isOutput=true]$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
      name: setvarStep


In the dependent stage Test_All, get the variable:
    variables:
       myVarfromStageA: $[ stageDependencies.Build_without_analysis.jobBuildAll.outputs['setvarStep.directory'] ]


In the jobs, you can go into that directory to have the code.

You can check the doc for the variable usage.

Now that's an interesting idea, I'll try it out!!!
But I still don't understand why all jobs use the same directory when all YAML is part of the product repository.

The behavior is controlled by agent. When you checkout different repository resource in different jobs, it could use different folder as workspace.  In addition, when you try the yaml above, please make sure the jobs are running on same agent as not sure how many agents meets demands BuildServer on your pool.

That's a useful option, thanks! It works, but seems to need a dependsOn: between  stages. Right now I'm considering a change to my workflow, by making unit tests and static code analysis part of the actual build jobs. Then I would have only artifacts to publish/download for another stage, and it doesn't matter if the working directory changes.

Thanks @HaraldJ. Glad to know it helps! Yes, it needs dependsOn for variable transfer. If you have any queries, feel free to raise a new ticket and always glad to help. Happy day! :)

Jobs are assigned to agents without any assumptions. It's your job to ensure all the required things are there when a job starts. The agent could be a different machine, it could be a completely new VM every time (as with the hosted agents) and it sure can be a different working folder on the agent every time.
So either your workflow should upload and download pipeline artifacts between jobs, and/or should checkout the repository at the start of each job. If you want to ensure all your files are there, don't split the workflow up into multiple jobs, but just run everything from the first one.
In your pipeline, always reference the pre-populated wellknown variables: $(Build.SourcesDirectory) or $(Pipeline.Workspace), those should wlways point to the correct directory.
Use the publish: and download: to publish the results from an earlier job and download the again from a later one.

Thanks, @jessehouwing. The whole workflow, with many jobs, all using the same agent directory, worked perfectly well until I put anything YAML into a separate Git repository.
Now, both $(Build.SourcesDirectory) and $(Pipeline.Workspace) change from job to job, and I don't understand why. Might have to go back to having anything YAML within code repositories.

When using YAML templates form another repository:

Use the resources specification to provide the location of the templates repository
Refer to the templates repository using @ and the name you gave it in resources

Example:
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: mytemplates # <------------- repository name/alias
      type: github
      name: Contoso/BuildTemplates

jobs:
  - template: common.yml@mytemplates # Reference a YAML template in repository mytemplates

So in your case instead of /Base-pipeline.yml try using /Base-pipeline.yml@YAML:
resources:
  repositories:
    # ...

    - repository: YAML # <------------- repository name/alias
      type: git
      name: YAML-Automation
      ref: main
      trigger:
        - none

extends:
  template: /Base-pipeline.yml@YAML # Reference a YAML template in repository YAML
  parameters:
    productName: FOO

See Template usage reference for more details.

Thank you! Done that - replaced every .yml with .yml@YAML. Unfortunately, the problem is still the same.

@HaraldJ hold on - what do you mean by every .yml file? You should do that in FOO-pipeline.yml only, to reference templates from other repositories. The YAML-Automation repository is the one that contains the shared templates, right? Or are you using templates from other repositories as well?

Just noticed that, on both agents, the checkout produces an empty YAML-Automation file (the name: of the repository, and a YAML directory (- repository: YAML) with all YML-files. If I understand the documentation correctly, the checkout command uses the repo name, and not the repo's name: field. Could that be related to the problem?

the checkout command uses the repo name - the correct syntax would be checkout: YAML. But you don't need to explicitly use a checkout task to use the YAML templates, UNLESS there you use other files such as json, xml etc. Try removing the checkout task first.
